# How to consolidate loops for code to t/f data btw. wkshts based on 2 conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I found the code below and modified it from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AzhQ5KiNybk – “Transfer Specific Worksheet Range Data from one worksheet to another based on condition”

CODE OVERVIEW: I used the VBA Excel code below in Excel 2013 to copy data from columns F to Y in a wksht called CPDesign and paste it to columns H to AA in a wksht called Design (in the same wkbk) by using a lookup value. It looks up the values, I’ve defined as NodeA and NodeB, in column B of the CPDesign wksht and looks up its match in column C of Design wksht and then copies and pastes the corresponding data as described above.

EXAMPLE WKSHTS: **CPDesign** (the wksht I am copying the data from) has the Node names (what I call NodeA and NodeB) listed in a single column called Node. Ex:

```
Hub            Node       SourceTx           SourceRx
Allentown     V12345         14a                 3a     
Allentown     V78945         14b                 3b
Allentown     V33333         15a                 2a 
Allentown     V44444         15a                 2b
```

**Design** (the wksht I need to paste data to) has the NodeA and NodeB values listed in two different columns next to each other. A shortened version of the wksht below. Ex:

```
Hub       NodeA     NodeB    SourceTxA      SourceTxB      SourceRxB         
Allentown   V12345  V78945  (paste here)    (paste here)   (paste here)
Allentown   V33333  V44444  (paste here)    (paste here)   (paste here)
```

QUESTION: I took the code for NodeA and copied and pasted it below the loop for Node A and made it the loop for Node B. The code below works but I want to know how to consolidate the code for Node B with Node A loop so that it looks better? (I would like it to stay like the code I have and not turn it into something I don’t understand b/c I understand this code from the video, please:))

Thank you.

CODE:

```
Sub transfer()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrowCP As Long, lastrowD As Long
Dim NodeA As String
Dim NodeB As String

lastrowCP = Sheets("CPDesign").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrowCP

'CPDesign is spreadsheet I am copying data from
‘NodeA and NodeB are all in column B of CPDesign spreadsheet
NodeA = Sheets("CPDesign").Cells(i, "B").Value
NodeB = Sheets("CPDesign").Cells(i, "B").Value

'Design is spreadsheet I am copying data to
Sheets("Design").Activate
lastrowD = Sheets("Design").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'NodeA~~~

For j = 2 To lastrowD
'Design is Design what I'm pasting into
‘if value in NodeA column of CPDesign spreadsheet = value in column B of         
Design spreadsheet, then _
‘continue with code
If Sheets("Design").Cells(j, "B").Value = NodeA Then

Sheets("CPDesign").Activate
Sheets("CPDesign").Range(Cells(i, "F"), Cells(i, "Y")).Copy
Sheets("Design").Activate
Sheets("Design").Range(Cells(j, "H"), Cells(j, "AA")).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If

Next j
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next i

'NodeB~~~
'just repeated code above for NodeA except minus the Dim's. Can I consolidate this with Node A loop above so that it looks better?
lastrowCP = Sheets("CPDesign").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrowCP
NodeA = Sheets("CPDesign").Cells(i, "B").Value
NodeB = Sheets("CPDesign").Cells(i, "B").Value

Sheets("Design").Activate
lastrowD = Sheets("Design").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For j = 2 To lastrowD
‘if value in NodeB column of CPDesign spreadsheet = value in column C of Design spreadsheet, then _
‘continue with code
If Sheets("Design").Cells(j, "C").Value = NodeB Then

Sheets("CPDesign").Activate
Sheets("CPDesign").Range(Cells(i, "F"), Cells(i, "Y")).Copy
Sheets("Design").Activate
Sheets("Design").Range(Cells(j, "H"), Cells(j, "AA")).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If

Next j
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next i

'END NodeA and NodeB Loops~~~

'when data transferred can go to sheet 1
Sheets("Design").Activate
'and end routine by selecting cell A1
Sheets("Design").Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Main()

Dim wbCP As Worksheet: Set wbCP = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CPDesign")
Dim wbD As Worksheet: Set wbD = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Design")
Dim intLastrowCP As Integer: intLastrowCP = wbCP.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim intLastrowD As Integer: intLastrowD = wbD.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim intCountCP As Integer
Dim intCountD As Integer
Dim strCurrentCPNode As String

' Loop through CPDesign sheet
For intCountCP = 2 To intLastrowCP

    ' Get current Node in CPdesign
    strCurrentCPNode = wbCP.Cells(intCountCP, "B").Value

    ' Loop through Design sheet
    For intCountD = 2 To intLastrowD

        ' Does the node match NodeA in Design sheet
        If wbD.Cells(intCountD, "B").Value = strCurrentCPNode Then

            ' It does so set the SourcerTxA column value
            wbD.Cells(intCountD, "D").Value = wbCP.Cells(intCountCP, "C").Value

        ' Does the node match NodeB in Design sheet
        ElseIf wbD.Cells(intCountD, "C").Value = strCurrentCPNode Then

            ' It does so set SourceTxB and SourceRxB values
            wbD.Cells(intCountD, "E").Value = wbCP.Cells(intCountCP, "C").Value
            wbD.Cells(intCountD, "F").Value = wbCP.Cells(intCountCP, "D").Value

        End If

    Next

Next

' Clear objects
Set wbCP = Nothing
Set wbD = Nothing

End Sub
```

**NOTE**: code doesn't activate the sheet or the cell at the end but you already know how to do that :)

Comment: Thank you so much, Zac. The ElseIf. I'm looking through a website on how to do loops, so this is very timely. Thank you, again!

Comment: No problems, glad to help